# BlueJ - easy painting program | if-funktion (sum.kern)

Tags: java, paint, bluej

I'm having a problem with the if-funktion.

It should be:
             If (mouse is pressed) the pencil should follow the cursor and paint the way

else do nothing.

That is my code. Can not find the error

```
import sum.kern.*;

public class ZeichnePrgm
{
    // Objects
    Bildschirm derBildschirm;
    Stift derStift;
    Maus dieMaus;

    // Konstruktor
    public ZeichnePrgm()
    {
        derBildschirm = new Bildschirm();
        derStift      = new Stift();
        dieMaus       = new Maus();

    }

    // Dienste
    public void fuehreAus()
    {
        do
        {  
            if(dieMaus.istGedrueckt()) // mouse.isPressed
            {
             derStift.bewegeBis(dieMaus.hPosition(),dieMaus.vPosition()); //pen.moveTo
             derStift.runter(); // pen.down
            }
            else 
                derStift.hoch(); //pen.up
        }while(dieMaus.doppelKlick()); //pen.doubleClick

       /*  while(!dieMaus.doppelKlick())
        *  
        *  meinStift.runter(); // pen.down
        *  meinStift.bewegeBis(dieMaus.hPosition(),dieMaus.vPosition()); //pen.moveTo
        */  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? You haven't included enough detail to help you.

Comment: I am guessing it is because of your while loops condition (draw, while double click is being performed)

Comment: Can you translate the names to english. It will be easier for us to help

Comment: Hope it is somehow understandable now.